# R Replace values in multiply columns based on specified condition?

Tags: r, replace, multiple-columns

How can I replace 2nd to 7th values of "N" to "Y" in the first row ? the first value stays "N"

```
     SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1       N       N       N       N       N       N       N
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y
3       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N
```

My desire outcone is :

```
1       N       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y
```

Many thanks,

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- read.table("a.txt", sep = '\t', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a
     SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1       N       N       N       N       N       N       N
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y
3       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N
a[1,2:7] <- "Y"
a
     SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1       N       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y
3       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N
```

Ok, it's a bit tricky but possible to do. I will edit this answer. We want to change N to Y only in rows where from column 2:7 we have only N, sooo I added new column with value FALSE and TRUE. If row have only N from column 2:7 value is FALSE becase we have not any Y. I use

```
b$new <- apply(b[,2:7], 1, function(x) any(x %in% c("Y")))

     SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090   new
1       N       N       N       N       N       N       N     FALSE
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y     TRUE
3       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N     TRUE
```

Then if we have FALSE in column `new` we can put values Y in columns 2:7

```
b[,2:7][b$new==FALSE ,] <- "Y"
```

So we have desired result.

```
     SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090   new
1       N       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y     FALSE
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y     TRUE
3       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N     TRUE
```

Summarizing, each value in roww with value N in columns 2:7 will be replaced with Y.
Of course we dont need column `new` so we can remove it by

```
b$new <- NULL
```

Ok, so count occarances in columns and barplot:

```
x <- apply(a, 2, table)
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
```

Easy R bulit barplot

```
z <- as.data.frame(t(y))
barplot(data.matrix(z[1:2,]), col=c("darkblue","red"),beside=TRUE)
```

[image]

X-axis labels will expand, if you plot it by yourself.

There's other way to get this plot using ggplot package but I would have to re-build datafile what is a bit time consuming, cheers!

```
>dat
  SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1       N       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y
3       N       N       N       N       N       N       N
4       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N
5       N       Y       N       Y       N       N       N
6       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y
dat$new <- apply(dat[,1:7], 1, function(x) all(x %in% c("Y") | all((x %in% c("N")))))
result <- dat[dat$new!=TRUE, ]
result$new <- NULL
> result
  SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1       N       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y       Y
2       N       N       N       N       N       N       Y
4       N       N       N       N       N       Y       N
5       N       Y       N       Y       N       N       N
```

Comment: thanks! I have milions of rows with different combinations of "Y" and "N" ... is there a way to find all that all columns have "N" and replace values in the same columns as above ? Many thanks !

Comment: In a[1,2:7] <- "Y"  1 is a number of row and 2:7 are number of columns. If you want change N to Y in all rows and from column 2 to 7 type a[,2:7] <- "Y".

Comment: but will that work for rows with "N"s only ? I don't want to change rows that have other combination that 7 "N"s  for example                                          N       N       N       N       N       Y       N                                                ... thanks a milion

Comment: Sorry for delay, I had my job to do :) I edited the answer to desired solution.

Comment: Hi, One more question ... how can I count how many "Y"s and "N"s are in a given column ? also is there a way to have a graph showing these results for all columns ?  Thanks

Comment: You can count number of occurances N and Y in each column for example by x <- apply(a, 2, table). Now we can plot a joined barplot. Unfortunately I have a lot of work, so try to do this by yourself, I try tu put some answer and picture soon, cheers!

Comment: THANK YOU ! so kind of you! Cheers Artur

Comment: Solution added ^^

Comment: Brilliant! Much apprieciated!

Comment: Hi @Adamm I hope that you will be able to help me further with this data set. I need to subset the df so there are not the same values in one row. Basically I need to get rid of all rows that have all "Y" and "N" ... Thanks in advance! A

Comment: put 1up on the left side of my comments if you like

Comment: Hopefully you received it and can see it as I get msg that feedback from members with less than 15 reputation is recorded but doesn't change public display ...

Comment: ahh I see, if there any problems with this fell free to comment ;>

Comment: Hi @Adamm hope you are well. I have a different question ...require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("excel.xlsx") 
lst = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb)) setStyleAction(artsla,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE") lst = readWorksheet(artsla, sheet = getSheets(artsla), useCachedValues=TRUE) i use these codes to get workbook to R and then add  some values. When I seve the work book it removes the formulas that were in the original workbook. do you know how I can manipulate and save a workbook without formulas being removed. Thanks in advance A